# Problems managing CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, memory, titanium, commonjs

I am using Titanium Appcelerator to develop apps using JavaScript. They have suggested to use the CommonJS approach. A brief example on CommonJS can be found [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium).

For the life of me, I cannot still figure out how to structure my code.

Example:

```
/* Homescreen.js */
exports.createHomescreen = function () {

    //load all required modules first
    var videoPlayer = require('ui/videoPlayerModule');

    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%'
    })

    var newPlayer = videoPlayer.createPlayer({
        width:100
        height:50
    });

    self.add(newPlayer);
    return self;
}
```

The videoPlayerModule

```
/* videoPlayerModule.js */
exports.createPlayer = function (object) {

    //load all required modules first
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        width:object.width,
        height:object.height
    });

    var exitVideoButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width:100,
        height:50
    });

    exitVideoButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        self.close();    //When this window is closed, the memory isn't freed.
        self = null;     //Still the memory isn't cleared
    });

    self.add(exitVideoButton);

    return(self);
}
```

I am having memory allocation problems because whenever I load a videoPlayer and close it, the memory is never cleared. If I open the videoPlayer again, the memory is allocated AGAIN. Because of this, my app's memory usage increases every time the videoPlayer is launched.

I know my way of thinking is not right. I am overlooking something very simple here. Can anyone let me know what am I not doing right?

Comment: which Titanium SDK do you use and for which platform?

Comment: I'm using the latest Titanium SDK (3.0)
And I'm building for iOS

Comment: Well there was an issue related to this. It usually should be fixed with 3.0.2.GA. I guess you already had a look at [Memory Management](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Managing_Memory_and_Finding_Leaks) for Titanium.

Comment: How is "createHomescreen" being used? I think it likely the memory leak is happening a step above what you've shown us. Come up with a complete example that demonstrates your leak, as simply as possible, and I can help.

Comment: Hi @DawsonToth Thanks for your input dude. I've figured out the problem. I have marked the answer as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are adding a `Ti.UI.Window` (created from videoPlayerModule.js), to another `Ti.UI.Window` (in Homescreen.js), which you should not be doing. `Ti.UI.Window` is a base container object, you never add it to anything (generally),  so when you close the window, it still stays referenced as one of the children of the container window, so it never goes away. Your `self = null;` does nothing at this point.

You need to replace your Window in video player with a View, I would try something like this instead:

```
/* videoPlayerModule.js */
exports.createPlayer = function (object) {

    var self = Ti.UI.createView({
        width:object.width,
        height:object.height
    });

    var exitVideoButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width:100,
        height:50
    });

    exitVideoButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        self.hide();
    });

    self.add(exitVideoButton);

    return(self);
}
```

This is not a complete solution, as you still will have the view in memory, but it is a much much smaller footprint then a full fledged window, a better way to do this would be to create this once, then `show()` or `hide()` it when needed in the context of the Homescreen, another way would be to pass the parent and then remove the view from its parent when exited, but this solves your memory issue.

Comment: Yes! Got it @Josiah
I will try both the options you've mentioned. Thanks a lot dude :) Cheers.